# To which variable/array ajax/php saves XMLHttpReguest parameters after sending them in POST mode?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I get error 'Undefined index ...'. I'm sending request with parameters by XMLHttpRequest in POST mode. I don't know how to read sent parameters by target php script. I have such code:

```
function sendXML(location, strParams, redirectToOnSuccess)
{
    var xmlhttp; 

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

    else 
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange =
        function () 
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            {
                if (this.responseText == "OK")
                {
                    alert("Operacja zakończona sukcesem");
                    window.open("index.php", "_self");
                }

                else
                    alert("Coś poszło nie tak: " + this.responseText);
            }
        }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", location, true);               
    xmlhttp.send(strParams);
}
// (...)

$str = "Database and username do not exist. Create new?\\n\\Username: " . $_POST["usr"] . "\\DB name: " . $_POST["db"] . "\\Host: " . $_POST["addr"] . "\\n\\nIf info is correct, press OK.";

$strParams = "'usrRoot=" . $_POST["usrRoot"] . "&passRoot=" . $_POST["passRoot"] . "&usr=" . $_POST["usr"] . "&pass=" . $_POST["pass1"] . "&db=" . $_POST["db"] . "&addr=" . $_POST["addr"] . "'";

//echo $strParams;

echo "<script>if (confirm('" . $str . "', 'Czy dane się zgadzają?')){sendXML('install_mom.php', " . $strParams . ", 'index.php');}</script>";
```

in 'install_mom.php' I have such line (one from many other)

```
$connection = new mysqli($_REQUEST["addr"], $_REQUEST["usrRoot"], $_REQUEST["passRoot"], "");
```

When I run script it tells me, that in `$_REQUEST["addr"]`, `addr` is undefined. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks Mike.

Comment: Do you send database access meaning host (addr), user (usrRoot) and password (passRoot) in ajax request as parameters? That line from install_mom.php assumes that you do. BTW it is usually not very good idea to send that in request from client. This rather should be stored in some config file.

Comment: Dzięki, Zbyszku. Thanks Zbyszek. I've solved my problem. I don't know what was wrong, but now I'm creating paramsTable as ```var param = new FormData();```, and I add parameters by ```param.append('key', 'value');```. Afret all i pass it to send method: ```xmlhttp.send(param);```. Don't worry. I save data in php file. It is install file, and when it aplies, it remembers data in PHP file.